# Sql query on How to retrieve the value from root node in xml column

Tags: sql, xml

I am new to XML queries in SQL, and was hoping some one could help me with an Sql query on how to retrieve the type value.

I have an xml column data as shown below

```
<mnt:job xmlns:mnt="http://namespaces.aada.be/4.0/maintenance"
xmlns:order="http://namespaces.aadasoftware.net/4.4/maintenance/order" 
mnt:version="1.0" mnt:type="Aada.Core.Orders.DownloadOrder, Aada.Core">
<mnt:targets>
<mnt:target mnt:id="bf321a20-8283-4760-a683-57892d8b9e12" mnt:status="Succeeded" 
mnt:duration="00:00:00" mnt:message="" mnt:attempt="1">
<mnt:custom>
 .................
```

I wanted to retrieve the `value("Aada.Core.Orders.DownloadOrder, Aada.Core")` inside `mnt:type` but was not sure on how to write the query for it.

Appreciate the Help

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@` to get the attribute:

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<mnt:job xmlns:mnt="http://namespaces.aada.be/4.0/maintenance"
                    xmlns:order="http://namespaces.aadasoftware.net/4.4/maintenance/order" 
                    mnt:version="1.0" mnt:type="Aada.Core.Orders.DownloadOrder, Aada.Core">
                        <mnt:targets>
                            <mnt:target mnt:id="bf321a20-8283-4760-a683-57892d8b9e12" mnt:status="Succeeded" 
                            mnt:duration="00:00:00" mnt:message="" mnt:attempt="1" />
                        </mnt:targets>
                    </mnt:job>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://namespaces.aada.be/4.0/maintenance' AS mnt)
SELECT  @X.value('(/mnt:job/@mnt:type)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
```

Comment: thanks for that Gareth
I tried this and it worked, but appreciate the help thanks a lot

    select [Data].value('declare namespace 
    x="http://namespaces.aada.be/4.0/maintenance";((/x:job/@x:type)
    [1])','nvarchar(max)') as Result

 FROM [aada].[dbo].[tblMAINTENANCEJOBHISTORY]